# Why `npx react-native init` command creates typescript project?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

Recently react-native's version got updated and when I try to create new project using `npx react-native init MyProject` command it generates project in TypeScript by default.

How do I create it in JavaScript?

I tried making project with:-

1. `npx create-react-native-app`
2. `npx create-expo-app`
3. Using `ignite-cli`
4. `npx react-native init --template react-native-template-blank`

The first 2 commands creating expo bare-project.
The third command is generating typescript and The fourth command is throwing and Error:-

```
error Error: Command failed: npm install --save --save-exact react-native-template-blank
npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS
npm ERR! No versions available for react-native-template-blank
```

Comment: You just replace app.tsx with app.js

Comment: @leandronn No, I didn't find any solution. I just followed the advice of darshilsakhiya